# Split one long comma string into multi column new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I am newish to SQL to please excuse any ignorance.  I have a table, called 'temp' that contains one Field with one long comma seperated string, thus:

```
Field1
Apples,oranges, pears, berries, melons
```

I want to insert the above into an existing table, 'Detail' that has predfined columns, so it would look like this:

```
Field1   Field2   Field3  Field4   Field5
Apples   Oranges  Pears   Berries  Melons
```

I've been reading the forums and I take it I need to use a function - however how do I actully do this?  And which function is best?  Some are saying a XML function is best?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Can you add which database engine you are doing this in please?

Comment: This breaks normalization.  You should be aware of all the adverse consequences before you proceed.

Comment: To clarify duffymo's comment: there should (probably) be a separate record for each fruit value, rather than having one record with 5 different columns, each with a different fruit. However, your proposed structure is still better than having one field with five different values inside it (separated by commas).

Comment: sorry - SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH Split_Fields (Field, xmlfields)
AS
(
    SELECT Field1 AS Field,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>'  
    + REPLACE(Field1,',', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields
      FROM Table1
)

 SELECT Field,      
 xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1,    
 xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2,
 xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3,    
 xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4,
 xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5
 FROM Split_Fields
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38455/1)**

OR

```
SELECT Field,
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
Field1 AS Field
,CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>' + REPLACE(Field1,',', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields 
FROM Table1
) Split_Fields
```

To **insert into another table** (ex: Detail) try below

```
;WITH Split_Fields (Field, xmlfields)
AS
( 
SELECT 
Field1 AS Field
,CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>' + REPLACE(Field1,',', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields 
FROM Table1
) 

INSERT INTO Detail
SELECT 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4, 
xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5 
FROM Split_Fields
```

Comment: thanks for this - so is the above a function that I will need to create?  I am ultimatley wanting to use reporting services via a stored procedure - how do I call the above from the SP?

Comment: @user2470603 if you have comma separated column with multiple rows and need to convert to multiple columns then above query works perfectly. If you have other case please provide the sample data with  table structure.

Comment: apologies but I am lost. Is the above a function I need to create?

Comment: Sorry but I am quite new to SQL and do not understand.  I pasted this into the SP but at the WITH statements it says its expecting ')'

Comment: If you are still getting error paste your SP in your question so that i can help you

Comment: Here is my code:;WITH Split_Fields (Field, xmlfields)AS(
SELECT Field1 AS Field,CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>' + REPLACE(Field1,',', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields
      FROM Temp
  )

 SELECT Field,      
   xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1,    
   xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2,
   xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3,    
   xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4,
   xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5
 FROM Split_Fields

Comment: How do I actually insert into the Detail table though?

Comment: Now this ;WITH Split_Fields(Field, xmlfields)AS(SELECT Field1 AS Field,CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>'+ REPLACE Field1,',', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields
FROM _Temp)INSERT INTO Detail (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5) 
SELECT Field,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]','varchar(100)') AS Field1, xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]','varchar(100)') AS Field2,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]','varchar(100)') AS Field3, xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]','varchar(100)') AS Field4, xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]','varchar(100)') AS Field5 FROM Split_Fields

Comment: But now I receive this error: The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.  Even though I have specified 5 in the insert and select?

Comment: check the updated answer..  just need to remove 'Field' column name as it is not present in your 'detail' table

Comment: Thank you for your help.  However, the query has been executing for 6 mins and is still running.  There are 130,000 records - should it be taking this long?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(SUBSTR(r_str, 1, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 1) - 1), ' ') AS r_substr_1
,       REPLACE(SUBSTR(r_str, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 1) + 1, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 2) - INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 1) - 1), ' ') AS r_substr_2
,       REPLACE(SUBSTR(r_str, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 2) + 1, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 3) - INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 2) - 1), ' ') AS r_substr_3
,       REPLACE(SUBSTR(r_str, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 3) + 1, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 4) - INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 3) - 1), ' ') AS r_substr_4
,       REPLACE(SUBSTR(r_str, INSTR(r_str, ',', 1, 4) + 1), ' ')    AS r_substr_5
FROM
(
        SELECT  'Apples, oranges, pears,berries, melons' r_str FROM DUAL
);

Result: Apples  oranges pears   berries melons
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually sql is used for structured data, and a comma separated string would come from an outside data file. If you have the outside data file available, load the data like this. Or consider exporting your original temp table to a data file if you have to.

```
bulk insert tbl_fruits from file.csv with fieldterminator=','
```