# how to merge the value of two rows in one 'Duplicate IDs'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have tried to find the answer but whatever I found did not apply to my situation, so I will appreciate any help on this:

Scenario : I have clients with ID's and personal information in one table and then I have another table that indicates notes that are belongs to these ID's.
when I join the tables I get multiple notes in multiply rows. as shown below.

```
T1. ID -T1. Name    -T1. Birthday   -T2. Note                  -Row number
2      -Peter       -11/20/1990     -deciding                  -1
2      -Peter       -11/20/1990     -purchased                 -2
3      -David       -12/22/1962     -Presentation scheduled    -1  
3      -David       -12/22/1962     -Presentation completed    -2
3      -David       -12/22/1962     -Purchased                 -3
4      -Anna        -5/07/1992      -Ignored                   -1
```

What I was wandering is how can I add the note 2 and 3 at the end of first row and get rid of duplicates?

```
T1. ID -T1. Name    -T1. Birthday   -T2. Note               -Note_2      -Note_3
2      -Peter       -11/20/1990     -deciding               -purchased  
3      -David       -12/22/1962     -Presentation scheduled -Presentation -completed    Purchased
4      -Anna            -5/07/1992  -Ignored                -Null        -Null
```

you can use this query to see the tables:

```
declare  @t1  table ( ID int not null,
                      Name varchar (50),
                      birthday date)

declare @t2 table (ID int not null,
                    Note nvarchar(max))


insert into @t1 values ( 2 , 'Peter' , '11/20/1990')
insert into @t1 values ( 3 , 'David' ,'12/22/1962')
insert into @t1 values ( 4 , 'Anna' , '5/07/1992')

insert into @t2 values (2 , 'deciding')
insert into @t2 values (2 ,'purchased')
insert into @t2 values (3 ,'Presentation scheduled')
insert into @t2 values (3 ,'Presentation completed')
insert into @t2 values (3 ,'Purchased')
insert into @t2 values (4 ,'Ignored')



SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.id) AS 'ROW NUMBER'
FROM @t1 as t1
left outer join @t2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Looking to your SQL code add seeing `declare  @t1  table` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY` and `@t1` i believe you are using SQL-server instead off MySQL. So please correct your tags.

Comment: Basically use ROW_NUMBER() to create incremented id per user then use PIVOT or conditional aggregation to put it together.  The one question I have though is will you always have x# of Notes in other words will it always be 3 or less?  If dynamic # of max notes that you want to include you would need to use dynamic SQL and Pivot/conditional aggregation to pull it off

Comment: @Matt thank you so much for your help Matt, the number can increase and it is not limited to 1-3.
I do not know much about Dynamic SQL and just recently start studying the concept. I will appreciate if you can refer me to good sources .

Comment: kind of depends on the platform you are using?  sql-server? I would search for your platform dynamic pivot and you should find some references.  The key to it will be creating a ROW_NUMBER on your notes table partitioned by user.  But be careful you don't really want to go too wide in columns so you might want a max so it doesn't get crazy.  Also you might consider a Notes field that concatenates the notes records into 1 field but I guess that depends on your use

Comment: @PedramSalamati Consider using the answer to the linked question as inspiration. Should be able to apply that answer to t2, and then add one more dynamic sql statement to get your final output by joining t1 to your pivoted t2. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468417/convert-unknown-number-of-comma-separated-varchars-within-1-column-into-multiple/37643784#37643784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an entire script for this. I get that it may not be as concise as the one above, but it works without any additional add ons and also is easy to explain.

The only thing I wasn't sure of was if you wanted three separate note columns or one column with concatenated notes. I went with the concatenated note method...

```
declare @t1 table
(
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(50),
    birthday date
)
declare @t2 table
(
    ID int not null,
    Note nvarchar(max)
)
insert into @t1
values
(2, 'Peter', '11/20/1990')
insert into @t1
values
(3, 'David', '12/22/1962')
insert into @t1
values
(4, 'Anna', '5/07/1992')
insert into @t2
values
(2, 'deciding')
insert into @t2
values
(2, 'purchased')
insert into @t2
values
(3, 'Presentation scheduled')
insert into @t2
values
(3, 'Presentation completed')
insert into @t2
values
(3, 'Purchased')
insert into @t2
values
(4, 'Ignored')

--Create table of all notes and what person they belong to.
declare @Notes table
(
    NoteID int not null,
    ID int not null,
    Note nvarchar(max)
)

--Insert into note table
insert into @Notes
(
    NoteID,
    ID,
    Note
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.note),
       t1.ID,
       Note
FROM @t1 as t1
    left outer join @t2 AS t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID

--Create a table of person ID and concatenated notes.
declare @ConcatNotes table
(
    ID int not null,
    Note nvarchar(max)
)

--Insert just people first
insert into @ConcatNotes
(
    ID
)
select distinct
    ID
FROM @Notes

declare @NoteCount int
declare @i int = 1

select @NoteCount = max(noteid)
from @Notes

--While loop to loop through ALL notes by person ID and concatenate with semicolon. Change semicolon to whatever you want.
while (@i <= @NoteCount)
BEGIN
    update a
    set Note = isnull(a.Note + ';', '') + b.Note
    --select *
    from @ConcatNotes a
        inner join @Notes b
            on a.id = b.ID
    where b.Noteid = @i
    set @i = @i + 1
END

--A select to show the person ID and the concatenated notes.
select *
from @ConcatNotes

--The final query you were looking for.
select a.*,
       b.Note
from @t1 a
    inner join @ConcatNotes b
        on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I preferred having notes on different columns  like note1 column = row number 1 , note2 column = row number 2. but based on your query I can get it done. however I have learned about pivoting tables and that might be the best approach to my situation but I have short knowledge about it and need to research to find how pivoting can apply into a situation like this.
Over all this answer gave me the result I was looking for. I truly appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

I found this CLR solution here:
https://groupconcat.codeplex.com
and utilized it successfully.

Essentially, your query would become:

```
;WITH example AS (
SELECT t1.id, t1.Name, t1.birthday, t2.id AS t2id, t2.Note 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.id) AS 'ROW NUMBER'
FROM @t1 as t1
left outer join @t2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
)
select ID, name, birthday, [dbo].[GROUP_CONCAT_D]( Note, '   -') AS Notes
from example
group by ID, name, birthday
```

The results look like this:

```
ID  name    birthday    Notes
2   Peter   1990-11-20  deciding   -purchased
3   David   1962-12-22  Presentation scheduled   -Presentation completed   -Purchased
4   Anna    1992-05-07  Ignored
```

Comment: thank you so much for putting time into this, I truly appreciate it.
However I could not Utilized this successfully.
I will do some research on the link you have sent and will try it again.

Comment: installation was very simple, but you need the SQL CLR enabled.

How to enable CLR:   
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/05/sql-server-2005-enable-clr-using-t-sql-script/

installation script:
https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1502310