# TSQL: transpose last 3 columns into rows?

Tags: t-sql, transpose

Been trying all sorts of transposing methods, including pivot, &
aggregation/CASE, but nothing seems to work properly.
Looking to transpose the last 3 columns (of a 5 column matrix) 
into the rows of each unique ID.  Image below.

This seems like such a simple problem.  There really ought to be
a simple solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: Transpose last 3 columns into rows?]

```
Here is the code to generate the temporary table:

-- -- BEGIN: Clean up temp tables: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
-- 
-- Remove the temporary table if it exists -- -- -- -- -- -- --
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StrongmanTempTable') is NOT NULL
  BEGIN
  -- PRINT N'Table exists.  Now deleting...';
  DROP TABLE #StrongmanTempTable
  END
-- 
-- --   END: Clean up temp tables: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -

CREATE TABLE #StrongmanTempTable
  (
  EntrantID      INT,
  Entrant        VARCHAR (64),
  Event          VARCHAR (64),
  Judge1Score    float,
  Judge2Score    float,
  )

INSERT INTO #StrongmanTempTable
VALUES
    (1, 'Bluto',    'Tire Flip',    9.0,    9.9),
    (1, 'Bluto',    'Vehicle Pull', 6.3,    9.8),
    (2, 'Mighty Mouse', 'Log Throw',    6.1,    7.7),
    (2, 'Mighty Mouse', 'Tire Flip',    7.2,    9.0),
    (3, 'Popeye',   'Vehicle Pull', 9.0,    8.3),
    (2, 'Mighty Mouse', 'Vehicle Pull', 7.4,    7.8),
    (3, 'Popeye',   'Log Throw',    8.0,    9.7),
    (1, 'Bluto',    'Log Throw',    8.2,    8.3),
    (3, 'Popeye',   'Tire Flip',    6.5,    9.2)



-- For testing:
SELECT * FROM #StrongmanTempTable
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions, but I would personally use a CTE. For the CTE to work, you'll need to include a `;` at the beginning to close any previous statements.

I assumed a `full outer join` just in case any `EntrantID` participated in one event and not another, if that's not the case change the `join` as you see fit.

```
; with log_throw as
    (
        select t.*
        from #StrongmanTempTable as t
        where t.[Event] = 'Log Throw'
    )
    , tire_flip as
    (
        select t.*
        from #StrongmanTempTable as t
        where t.[Event] = 'Tire Flip'
    )
    , vehicle_pull as
    (
        select t.*
        from #StrongmanTempTable as t
        where t.[Event] = 'Vehicle Pull'
    )
select l.EntrantID
, l.Entrant
, l.[Event]
, l.Judge1Score
, l.Judge2Score
, f.[Event]
, f.Judge1Score
, f.Judge2Score
, p.[Event]
, p.Judge1Score
, p.Judge2Score
from log_throw as l
full outer join tire_flip as f on l.EntrantID = f.EntrantID
full outer join vehicle_pull as p on l.EntrantID = p.EntrantID
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Tarheel--it works!

Unfortunately, this is just a simple example for a real
world problem.  My real issue has unknown "Events" so I can't
hard code them into the solution.

Is there a way take this into account?

Comment: You'd have to use Dynamic SQL. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468417/convert-unknown-number-of-comma-separated-varchars-within-1-column-into-multiple/37643784#37643784) other answer of mine would be the best place to start.